# Is there a way to pass a variable from an awk statement to a bash function as an argument?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, awk

I am trying to look a for some specific values from (such as 1 or 4 and 2 or 3) a text file using an `awk` statement in a bash script. If this value is found in the file (within the `awk` statement), then I want to call a function from outside the `awk` statement and pass it the found value as an argument.

My questions: (1) Is this possible? If so then how? (2) If it is not possible or there is a better way, then how?

Note that I am skipping the first two lines of the text file when searching the file. I am using GNU AWK. Let me know if further explanation is required.

**I apologize in advance for the cross-post but I did not get the answer I am looking for.

file.txt

```
Name  Col1  Col2  Col3  
-----------------------
row1  1     4     7        
row2  2     5     8         
row3  3     6     9
```

The actual `retrieve` functions are much more complex than in this simplified example. So I need to make a call to this function because I don't want to put this in the `awk` statement.

```
function retrieve {
    if [[ "$1" == "1" ]]; then
        echo "one beer on the wall"
    elif [[ "$1" == "4" ]]; then
        echo "four beers on the wall"
    fi
}

function retrieve2 {
    if [[ "$1" == "2" ]]; then
        echo "two beers on the wall"
    elif [[ "$1" == "3" ]]; then
        echo "three beers on the wall"
    fi
}

awk -F '\t' '
    FNR < 2 {next}
    FNR == NR {
        for (i=2; i <= NF; i++) 
        {
            if (($i == 1) || ($i == 4))
                printf(%s, "'retrieve "$i" '")    # Here is the problem

            if (($i == 2) || ($i == 2))
                printf(%s, "'retrieve2 "$i" '")    # Here is the problem
        }
    }

' file.txt
```

Comment: 1) you might want to state expected output for your input. More importantly though: 2) [put down the chocolate-covered banana and step away from the European currency systems](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/put-down-the-chocolate-covered-banana.html) - there might be a better way of doing what you need than calling `sh` from `awk` from `sh`, but you'll need to describe the problem more in-depth.

Comment: Please don't crosspost, you have [excellent answers on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24873717/is-there-a-way-to-pass-a-variable-from-an-awk-statement-to-a-bash-function-as-an)

Comment: why not put the bash code into a separate script that you call using [the system command](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/I_002fO-Functions.html)?

Answer (score 5):

An ugly way of doing this (i.e. causing a function call in shell based on output from `awk`) could look like this:

```
awk -F '\t' '
    FNR < 2 {next}
    FNR == NR {
        for (i=2; i <= NF; i++) {
            if (($i == 1) || ($i == 4))
                printf "retrieve %s\n", $i

            if (($i == 2) || ($i == 2))
                printf "retrieve2 %s\n", $i
        }
    }

' file.txt | while read l; do eval $l; done
```

However this might seriously backfire in some cases.

Comment: Your approach is interesting, IF it's acceptable to call the functions AFTER awk has finished processing (in other words: if there's no need to interleave awk output with shell-function output). To avoid the `eval` security risk, you could try the following, assuming there are no _quoted_ tokens (tokens with embedded whitespace) to deal with: `... | while read -ra args; do "${args[@]}"; done`. If you _do_ need to call the shell function from _within_ awk, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24875216/45375

Comment: Well you can always pass the shell function `$0` from `awk` as one of it's arguments, but it has to be properly quoted - which is exactly where it gets messy. The function exporting seems cleaner though.